# How to write a (numerical) function using another (numerical) function?

Tags: numerical-methods

(This might be a bizarre question, so please don't tell me "why do you want to do this?".)

I'm wondering whether there are methods or tricks or tools or... to write a function using another function (the specific language doesn't really matter).  For example, assume that you are given a function "power" defined as follows:

```
int power (int n) { return n == 0 ? 1 : 2 * power (n - 1); }
```

and assume that you are asked to write, using that function or (even better) by transforming that function, another one that computes for example the Lucas numbers (2, 1, 3, 4, 7, 11, 18, 29, 47, 76, 123, 199, 322, 521, ...).  Of course the trivial way to use the given function would be to do:

```
int lucas (int n) { ... + power (n) - power (n) + ... }
```

but this is not the kind of answer I'm looking for.  Likewise the trivial way to transform the function is to delete its body and writing another one instead, but again it's obviously not what I want to do.

Comment: There is a closed-form formula for computing the Lucas numbers that requires exponentation: `pow (0.5 + 0.5 * sqrt(5.0), n) + pow(0.5 - 0.5 * sqrt(5.0), n)`. Is that what you are referring to?

Comment: Yes and no. Yes because it is an answer for the given example (computing Lucas numbers with pow), but no because I'm asking whether there are methods to do this more generally (if you were given another function than "power" as a basis and another function than "lucas" to write).

Comment: In that case, your question is unclear (and I will vote to close because of that). Generally speaking, there are many cases where one mathematical function can be expressed in terms of another, e.g. `tan(x) = sin(x) / cos(x)`. Those are mathematical identities, and a connection to a programming problem (what this site is about) isn't clear. For mathematical identities, you might want to inquire on [Mathematics Stackexchange](http://math.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I agree with you, this question might be be better suited for Mathematics Stackexchange. The connection with programming (at least in my mind) is that a numerical sequence can be (and often is?) defined by a function (in the programming sense).

Answer (score 0):

Yes. 
That is pretty standard in many languages.

Functions take some sort of input parameters and may call other functions or itself, and eventually return some sort of value.

If you have a specific language in mind, someone might show you a
straightforward example.

Comment: Of course (perhaps it's not that obvious from my question after all...) I know this. What I'm asking is: given a numerical function (for example "pow"), is there in general a method to write another numerical function (for example "lucas") in which the given function ("pow") is used (and does something useful in the computation).

Comment: Yes.   The general method is to just call the function.